# How to activate BharatQR on my Razorpay account? I am using test mode account

Tags: android

I want to add scan and pay using Razorpay using android app.any help would be appreciated.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

please raise a ticket using this [link](https://razorpay.com/support/). the feature flag needs to be enabled.